# How to Mock UriInfo in Arquillian test

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I created a REST webservice which uses `UriInfo`:

```
class Endpoint implements Resource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;


    @Override
    public Response doMagic() {
        // do magic
    }
}
```

Deployed to my container, this works nicely, but I have an Arquillian test, too:

```
@Test
public void test(@ArquillianResteasyResource Resource api) throws Exception {
    try (final Response response = api.doMagic()) {
        // test magic
    }
}
```

Which throws the following exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:186)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:330)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:238)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
```

The exception makes sense, the Arquillian tests don't test the actual REST webservice, but the beans. So of course there is no webservice context, which includes the `UriInfo`.

I guess to solve this I have to mock `UriInfo` somehow. Yet I couldn't find out how to mock beans that are injected with `@Context`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's not exactly mocking, but at least it works now. I changed my code to the following:

```
class Endpoint implements Resource {

    @Override
    public Response doMagic(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        // do magic
    }
}
```

And call it in my test case like this:

```
@Test
public void test(@ArquillianResteasyResource Resource api) throws Exception {
    try (final Response response = api.doMagic(new TestUriInfo())) {
        // test magic
    }
}
```

Where `TestUriInfo` returns the values I want to have.